# Command sleep to pause for 20 seconds if condition is met

Tags: php, sleep

I want to do the following: if  **$start** is a multiple of 28, the script will pause for 20 seconds and then continue work.

For this I wrote:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Moscow"); 
$start = 0;
$end = 2000;

for($start = 0; $start < 20; $start++){
if($start % 28 == 0){sleep(20);echo 'sleep ';}
echo date('H:i:s').'<br>';
}
```

When I use it, I get:

```
sleep 14:51:01
14:51:01
14:51:01
14:51:01
14:51:01
14:51:01
14:51:01
14:51:01
14:51:01
14:51:01
14:51:01
14:51:01
14:51:01
14:51:01
14:51:01
14:51:01
14:51:01
14:51:01
14:51:01
14:51:01
```

So I can see the script is not working right...

Can you please tell me why the script is not working right ?

Comment: And it will not work since `$i%28` will never equal to 0 if 0<$i<20 (in your case condition will work only for 0 value - therefore, only for first iteration and you still will not see a difference in rows)

Comment: Maybe your confusion is that zero is a multiple of 28? Depending on what you really want (I can't parse your initial sentence) you could check whether `($start % 28) == 27` at the end of the loop, which will be true after every 28 iterations.

Comment: Probably you wanted to write `$start < $end` ?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I want make that if  value **$start** will be multiples value 28 script will be paused on 20 secounds and script continue work. How right make it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that loop:

```
for($start = 0; $start < 20; $start++){
if($start % 28 == 0){sleep(20);echo 'sleep ';}
echo date('H:i:s').'<br>';
```

And last value element **$start** in loop 20.

For loop more taht 1 need use value **$start** > 56, becose `if($start % 28 == 0)`.

For example - `28*2 //for 2 loop.`

Answer (score 0):

Technically, 0 is a multiple of 28, and your program does work according to that, so I guess that this is simply not what you want. There are two ways I can imagine, maybe in code we understand each other better:

```
// 1. Sleep after every 28 times outputting current date:
for($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++) {
    echo date('H:i:s').'<br>';
    if($i % 28 == 27) {
        echo 'sleeping...<br>';
        sleep(20);
    }
}

// 2. Sleep before every 28th time outputting the current date, except the first time:
for($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++) {
    if($i != 0) && (($i % 28) == 0)) {
        echo 'sleeping...<br>';
        sleep(20);
    }
    echo date('H:i:s').'<br>';
}
```

If neither of these give you the right idea, then you will have to clarify what exactly you mean.