# is there any way to sleep on each interval specified in php

Tags: php, sleep

i want introduce some sleep functionality into my code so that i can call a function at a specified(time or interval).

my desired output:

(1) at first 5`sec`

```
im called
```

(2) at 10`sec` (i,e 5sec + 5 sec)

```
 im called    // at first iteration of loop



im called      // at second iteration of loop
```

right now i'm using

```
function curl_grab(){
  echo "im called<br/>";
}

$arr = ['http://ab.com/','http://bc.com/'];

foreach($arr as $el){
   curl_grab($el);
   sleep(5);
}
```

but the problem with the above code is it is dumping everything at a time

like so

```
im called
im called
```

i want it one by one

here is demo:   http://phpio.net/s/ggr

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634546/command-sleep-to-pause-for-20-seconds-if-condition-is-met

Comment: @SougataBose, the code dumps everything at the same time but i want something like javascript setTimeout()

Comment: PHP buffers the output.  You can attempt to force flush the output but there are a lot of other things that may get in way. 
flush(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a browser to test this code, you will be able to see the output together only, becoz you will see output after execution of php code is completed only. You can execute this in terminal to see the out put when it happens.

Write this code into test.php

```
function curl_grab(){
  echo "im called\n";
}

$arr = ['http://ab.com/','http://bc.com/'];

foreach($arr as $el){
   curl_grab($el);
   sleep(5);
}
```

To execute in terminal you can type

```
$ php /path/to/test.php
```

Comment: thanks alot i got the things thank you very much for your instant help